# SKlearn classifier's predict_proba doesn't sum to 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a classifier (in this case, it is the sklearn.MLPClassifier), with which I'm trying to perform classification into one of 18 classes.

The class is thus **multi-class**, not multi-label. I'm trying to predict only a single class.

I have my training data:  X `X.shape = (103393, 300)`  and Y `Y.shape = (103393, 18)`, where the target Y is a one-hot encoded vetctor, denoting the target class.

> EDIT in response to @Dr. Snoopy: I do not supply any labels -- I simply pass the 18-dimensional vector with the corret class' index corresponding to the 1 in the vector, and all others being 0 (One hot encoded vector).
> To prove that the vectors are correctly 1-hot encoded, I can run

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(Y.sum(axis=1)).value_counts()
```

> This returns 103393 counts of 1. Vectors are correctly 1-hot encoded, even upon examination.

When I fit the model, and return the class probability for all classes, the probability vector does not sum up to 1. Why might that be?

Here is an example of how I run the fitting:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = get_data()

model = MLPClassifier(max_iter=10000)
model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
probability_vector = model.predict_proba(X_test[0, :].respahe(1,-1))
```

Some of the time, the outputs are pretty close to 1. I suspect the error is probably due to rounding.

In other cases, the outputs sum to ~0.5 or less. Example output:

```
probability_vector = list(model.predict_proba(X_test[301,:].reshape(1,-1))[0])
print(probability_vector)
>>> [1.7591416e-06,
 3.148203e-05,
 3.9732524e-05,
 0.3810972,
 0.059248358,
 0.00032832936,
 8.5996935e-06,
 9.0914684e-05,
 9.377927e-07,
 0.0007674346,
 1.5543707e-06,
 0.0008467222,
 0.009655427,
 2.5728454e-05,
 1.07812774e-07,
 0.00022920035,
 0.00050288404,
 0.013878004]

len(probability_vecto)

>>> 18

sum(probability_vector)
>>> 0.46675437349917814
```

Why might this be happening? Is my model initialized incorrectly?

> Note: A couple of possible reasons for the error & my comments on them:
>
> - Class imbalance: The classes in the dataset are indeed, imbalanced. However, the non-1 summation problem is happening in well represented classes too, not just the underrepresented ones. Could this be a consequence of a model, which is not expressive enough?
> - Model uncertainty: "The model may not have a high level of confidence in its predictions for every input. " Is that all it is?

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: This is not enough, is your task multi-class or multi-label? How do the labels look like?

Comment: Hi @Dr.Snoopy, I edited my post to denote the answers to your questions, but am also responding here. It's a multi-class task. I do not supply any labels -- I simply pass the one-hot encoded vector as the Y. Am I doing something wrong here? How should I do this?

Comment: Your probability_vector has 19 entries, while you mention you only had 18 classes. Are you sure your one-hot encoded vectors is correct and your Y.shape = (103393, 18)?

Comment: @DJanssens I must have made a mistake when pasting my answer here. I edited the example outputs. The output is of length, my one_hot_encodings are correct and my output shape is as specified. I'm adding a "proof" test to check this into the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not one-hot encode your Y. The MLP classifier will do that for you using [LabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer) and then it will apply the softmax function correctly.
With multiple dimensions it will do multi-label classification.

Some explaining is done in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html)

---

You can check this for example by accessing `model.out_activation_` or `LabelBinarizer().fit(Y).y_type_` which should be *softmax/multiclass* , but here it will be *logistic/multilabel-indicator*

What you get at the moment are the logistic outputs of the individual classes.